# Using " Is NULL/not NULL" in LINQ To SQL

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

i would like to translate this request in LINQ to SQL:

```
SELECT * from Agir where NouvelIncident='1' AND facturable is null
```

My try:

```
 public static List<Agir> GetINDEFAgir()
 {
     DataClassesActilogDataContext db = ContextSingleton.GetDataContext();

     List<Agir> list;

     var v = from i in db.Agir
             where i.facturable is null && i.NouvelIncident == true
             select i;

     list = v.ToList();
     return list;

 }
```

Looks like "is null" is not allowed in LINQ to SQL... i have a mistake.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `==`, `'is'` is to check types

```
public static List<Agir> GetINDEFAgir()
 {

 DataClassesActilogDataContext db = ContextSingleton.GetDataContext();

 List<Agir> list;

 var v = from i in db.Agir
         where i.facturable == null && i.NouvelIncident == true
         select i;

 list = v.ToList();
 return list;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
var v = from i in db.Agir
             where i.facturable == null && i.NouvelIncident == true
             select i;
```

Linq-to-SQL should translate that to the proper SQL.